# make <li> change color on hover

Tags: css, html5-canvas

I have implemented an off-canvas menu. I want to make the whole `<li>` change color on hover but only the text are changing color. How can i do so?

PLease check the full code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/nia24/u7gLwx49/

Comment: Have you tried "Run code snippet" on this very page? Because it's behaving as you've described - the background changes, not the text. What do you actually want to happen?

Comment: When I run your code snippet (directly here on SO via the button) the whole LI _does_ change background color. I'm using Chrome, what browser(s) are you seeing only the text get the color change?

Comment: yes true, but it is not working on my browser. even i am using chrome

Comment: The background color changes on the hover of li. Actually what is your requirement? Do you mean to change the color of text on the hover of li?

Comment: If you are using external css, check if it is loaded.

Comment: which browser you are testing? The older versions of IE will not support hover for LI. Are you testing on something like that?

Comment: No it is on chrome.i just update the full codes here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no class *menu* in the fiddle, so:

```
<ul id="toggle" class="menu">
```

And be aware of space between *li* and *:hover*:

```
.menu li:hover{
    background: #00ff99;
}
```

Now, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/u7gLwx49/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

`.menu li:hover a {
  color: #FFFFF;
}`

Text will change color when hover is on *li* element